# How does (perl) Xerces validation access http schemas?

Tags: xml, perl, schema, xerces

This self contained example (pathname: `/root/stef/test.pl`) works fine on a server `A-OK`, while it doesn't work on another server `B-NOK`.

```
      1 use strict;
      2 use XML::Validate::Xerces;
      3
      4 sub main {
      5     my $rsep = $/;
      6     undef $/;
      7     my $xml = <DATA>;
      8     $/ = $rsep;
      9
     10     warn "working on this xml:[\n$xml]";
     11
     12     my %options;
     13     my $validator = new XML::Validate::Xerces(%options);
     14     my $valid = $validator->validate($xml) ? '' : 'in';
     15     warn "Document is ${valid}valid\n";
     16 }
     17
     18 main();
     19
     20 __DATA__
     21 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     22 <note
     23   xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
     24   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     25   xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd">
     26   <!--
     27   xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com file:///root/stef/note.xsd">
     28   -->
     29   <to>Tove</to>
     30   <from>Jani</from>
     31   <heading>Reminder</heading>
     32   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
     33 </note>
```

If I swap lines *25* and *27* (i.e. I change `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd` to be `file:///root/stef/note.xsd`) so with the schema as a local file, then it works fine even in `B-NOK`.

The only difference then seems when the schema is on http.

Note that, the local file was downloaded as `wget http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd` so that not only I know that the content of the schema file is the same (local & remote) but also that `http:80` works fine to catch stuff out there.

I didn't do anything special to have Xerces working over http:80 for server `A-OK`.
I would then expect to do nothing on server `B-NOK` to have Xerces going out there and grab the schema.

I didn't find clear info if/how Xerces should be instructed to use http. Neither which mechanism it has built-in, to behave like wget to download URLs.
I cannot understand then if I must add some config vars.
The admin of server `B-NOK` told me that he didn't see anything attempting to reach `http://www.w3schools.com` apart when doing the manual `wget`. This does seem Xerces doesn't bother at all to get that URL.

Really thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: *http:80 works fine* -  in your code you use `https:` (443)

Comment: Thank @clamp for having a look. The schema at line `25` is actually on http (is the 2nd url after the space on that line). The other urls (http & https at line 23 / 24 and first at 25 don't seem to play a real role, because as said swapping line 25 & 27 they are all still there and the validation works). Nothing changes with ALL urls set to http (as that `w3schools.com` provides even them) and ALL with https (as B-NOK has 443 open, I just used http for the schema because wget gave me a further confirmation of that working fine.

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work - tell us how it fails. Diagnosis always starts by looking at the symptoms.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com - I think they're still not a great resource.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay. It's a C library. Debugging my example step by step you can only reach this point: https://metacpan.org/release/XML-Validate/source/lib/XML/Validate/Xerces.pm#L59 (which for reference I call file `V` at line 59)and there is no way to step further. In `A-OK` that atomic instruction doesn't fail and goes to next instruction (same file `V` at line 61)  while on `B-NOK` there is an exception (inside the binary of the library) and I found myself on the next instruction (same file `V` at line 141)

Comment: This question was also [asked](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11131004) on PerlMonks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source:

```perl
if ($strict) {
        TRACE("Using strict validation");
        $DOMparser->setValidationScheme("$XML::Xerces::AbstractDOMParser::Val_Auto");
        $DOMparser->setIncludeIgnorableWhitespace(0);
        $DOMparser->setDoSchema(1);
        $DOMparser->setDoNamespaces(1);
        $DOMparser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(1);
        $DOMparser->setLoadExternalDTD(1);
        $DOMparser->setExitOnFirstFatalError(1);
        $DOMparser->setValidationConstraintFatal(1);
} else {
        TRACE("Using no validation");
        $DOMparser->setValidationScheme("$XML::Xerces::AbstractDOMParser::Val_Never");
        $DOMparser->setDoSchema(0);
        $DOMparser->setDoNamespaces(0);
        $DOMparser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(0);
        $DOMparser->setLoadExternalDTD(0);
}
```

Notice the `setLoadExternalDTD` setting is only true in strict validation mode.

Using the following should do the trick:

```perl
my $validator = XML::Validate::Xerces->new( strict_validation => 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you @ikegami. That code is file `V` (line _83_) (with file `V` the reference I used before in replying to @MichaelKay, so short for [V](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-Validate/source/lib/XML/Validate/Xerces.pm). `strict_validation` is already set to `1` by default (file`V` line _16_) and the strict branch is indeed the one taken while debugging. I confirm that I enter that branch for both the schema local and remote. As said there is no difference between local and remote till file `V` line _59_ where the remote scenario fails.

Comment: I wasn't given details but network settings on B-NOK server and behind have been performed and currently that fixed my issue. Nevertheless I tag this as a solution because even though incidentally `strict_validation` (as documented in my previous answer) is already set to 1, it's this the value which discriminates to access a schema (both local and remote, so on http(s)), and thus setting it explicitly to 1 guarantees the correct behaviour in any case, so it's the good answer to my original question.